# Joomla Eliminate render-blocking CSS

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have read the article https://www.giftofspeed.com/defer-loading-css/, and http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/loading-css-without-blocking-render/.

I have added some css through $document->addStyleSheet

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vnsinfo.com%2Fsilva%2F&tab=desktop

but I see there are some render  blocking css. You can check the same from:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vnsinfo.com%2Fsilva%2F&tab=desktop

How can I add the line onload="if(media!='all')media='all'" through $document->addStyleSheet ?

Alternatively, can I use this below code for Joomla css for use external css?

```
<noscript id="deferred-styles">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="small.css"/>
    </noscript>
    <script>
      var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
        var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
        var replacement = document.createElement("div");
        replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
        document.body.appendChild(replacement)
        addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
      };
      var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
          webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
      if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
      else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();    
$document->addCustomTag('<noscript id="deferred-styles"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="small.css"/></noscript>');
$document->addScriptDeclaration("
      var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
        var addStylesNode = document.getElementById('deferred-styles');
        var replacement = document.createElement('div');
        replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
        document.body.appendChild(replacement)
        addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
      };
      var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
          webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
      if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
      else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
   ");
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added the code along with the css name/path, but seems the css not loaded. Can you please explain me? Or suggest me some alternate way?

Comment: I think may be possible ,can you try this joomla custom html module , , ,https://support.ecwid.com/hc/en-us/articles/207807825-How-to-add-Javascript-code-to-articles-or-Custom-HTML-modules-in-Joomla